# Realizar duas inserções seguidas e dependentes no MySQL com Node JS

Tags: mysql, node.js

Bom Dia Pessoal.

Estou com um problema e preciso da ajuda de vocês.

Meu caso é o seguinte: Possuo uma tabela TAREFA e uma tabela de DIAS_TAREFA que tem uma chave estrangeira para id_tarefa. Portanto, após armazenar os dados de uma tarefa, tendo sucesso, devo inserir os dados na tabela DIAS_TAREFA de acordo com o id gerado anteriormente.
O problema que estou encontrando diz respeito as "threads" que estão rodando pois a função cadastrar da tarefa termina antes do retorno da função diasTarefaController.cadastrar() e com isso o sistema trava. 
Estou usando async await mas não está adiantando.

Código da função cadastrar da tarefa

```
async function cadastrar(req, res){
var {descricao, id_categoria, hora_inicio, hora_fim, data_termino, id_usuario} = req.body.tarefa;

hora_inicio = hora_inicio==""?null:hora_inicio;
hora_fim = hora_fim==""?null:hora_fim;
data_termino = data_termino==""?null:data_termino;

const sql = "INSERT INTO TAREFA (DESCRICAO, ID_CATEGORIA, HORA_INICIO, HORA_FIM, DATA_TERMINO, ID_USUARIO) VALUES ?";

let values = [[descricao, id_categoria, hora_inicio, hora_fim, data_termino, id_usuario]];

conexao.query(sql, [values], async function (error, results, fields){
    if(error){
        return res.json({'erro':'Tarefa nao gravada'});
    }else{
        const retornoDias = await diasTarefaController.cadastrar(req,results.insertId);
        if(retornoDias){
            return res.json({'ok':'Tarefa gravada!'});    
        }  
    }
}).end;};
```

Codigo da função diasTarefaController.cadastrar():

```
async cadastrar(req, id_tarefa){
    const { segunda, terca, quarta, quinta, sexta, sabado, domingo} = req.body.dias;

    const sql = "INSERT INTO DIAS_TAREFA (ID_TAREFA, SEGUNDA, TERCA, QUARTA, QUINTA, SEXTA, SABADO, DOMINGO)  VALUES ?";

    const values = [[
        id_tarefa,
        segunda,
        terca,
        quarta,
        quinta,
        sexta,
        sabado,
        domingo
    ]];

    conexao.query(sql, [values], function(error, result, field){
        if(error){
            return false;
        }else{
            return true;
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: ta gerando algum tipo de erro explicito? ou só trava mesmo hora de gravar  a dias_tarefas?

Comment: Sem erros. Apenas trava mesmo.